# What is basic priority inheritance protocol and its working?

Tags: operating-system, task, scheduled-tasks, priority-inversion

I'm trying to grasp the concept of the Basic Priority Inheritance Protocol and its key properties. However, I'm struggling to find comprehensive and clear content on this topic. Could someone please provide an explanation of the Basic Priority Inheritance Protocol along with a practical example to help illustrate its usage? Any insights into its properties and how it mitigates priority inversion issues would be greatly appreciated.